# Gathering multiple statistics about a table in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have this data in a MSSQL table

```
type      status       
a         open
b         open
a         closed
a         closed
a         closed
b         open
c         closed
```

I can run this query to get a table like this
`select type,count(*) from table where status = 'open'`

```
a     1
b     2
```

Then I can do another query
`select type,count(*) from table where status = 'closed'`

```
a          2
c          1
```

How do I write a query that shows me a table like this

```
type        open         closed
a            1             2
b            2             0
c            0             1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will produce your desired result

```
select type,
    SUM(case when status = 'open' then 1 else 0 end) as [Open],
    SUM(case when status = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end) as [Closed]
from table
group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), have a look at the BOL or search any SQL site for some example of use.

Comment: To be honest bobs answer is a lot easier to implement than 'PIVOT', so go with that.

Comment: Bob's answer is easier to implement in only the most trivial cases.

Comment: @Eric - I disagree. I tend to find `PIVOT` is confined to trivial cases. If you want to start introducing more than one aggregate - well you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Created your table in SQL 2005 and confirmed the below works using the pivot command:

```
select * 
from (select type, status from table) test 
pivot ( count(status) for status in ([Open], [Closed] )) pivottable
```