# MySQL: How to query multiple 'statistics' in a single query?

Tags: php, mysql

This is more of a question rather than a problem that I need to solve. My backend is fast and my queries running great, so it's not *that* important. Okay, but let's get to it.

I have 4 panels of statistics on my dashboard regarding the number of views from today, yesterday, this week and this month; each taking up one query in my database. What I was wondering is, how would one put all those queries together to ease up the load on the database/server?

I was looking through Stackoverflow before asking and saw one saying something like:

```
SUM(case when status = 'open' then 1 else 0 end) as [Open],
SUM(case when status = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end) as [Closed]
```

Source: [Gathering multiple statistics about a table in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384516/gathering-multiple-statistics-about-a-table-in-a-single-query)

Which could be what I need, could be something like:

```
SUM(case when DATE(created_at) = '2015-07-23' then 1 else 0 end) as today,
SUM(case when DATE(created_at) = '2015-07-22' then 1 else 0 end) as yesterday,
SUM(case when WEEK(created_at) = '29' then 1 else 0 end) as week,
SUM(case when MONTH(created_at) = '7' then 1 else 0 end) as month
```

I was just wondering if anyone has some **better** suggestions, as I have applied this to my function and it works just fine.

Comment: While doing these kinds of things might help with the load on your server, they could also hinder it if the queries end up getting overly complicated; it really depends on the data needed and how powerful the server is.

Comment: You could cache the values, then invalidate the cache when needed.  Another approach could be using something like triggers and maintaining the actual measurements rather than calculating them.  Pros and cons to each.  Anyway, slowly changing temporal dimensions suggest something caching those at given interval.

Comment: Thanks! That makes great sense. I'll try both approaches and maybe see how they perform over time when I get more data. I'll try caching them, I won't need real-time updates anyway so might as well try :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments are giving good hints. I'll provide here another idea, that conceptually is used in most of the banks I've been working with.

When there are billions of rows, and you do not need exact instant snapshots for every request (meaning: you have a tolerance for slightly outdated data), it is worth exploring batch processes.

This is how it works:

1. You define your lag tolerance: for example: "I'm ok with data outdated 8 hours". This is the periodicity of your batch process.
2. You denormalize the database to add a "redundant" column/table storing running totals of your choice. For example, you would add a table called `statistics_snapshot` with 4 columns: (`timestamp`, `month`, `day`, `week`) or something of the like.
3. You create a stored procedure in mysql that fills up this table with your 4 queries, or with one global queries as you suggested. A timestamp is also registered so you know when it was taken.
4. You create a user with `EXECUTE` grant for that procedure, **ONLY**.

   ```
   CREATE USER 'cron_mysql_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'strongpassword';
   GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE db_name.proc_name TO 'cron_mysql_user'@'localhost';
   ```
5. You use <del>`DBMS_JOB`</del> a cron job to connect mysql and run this procedure with periodicity defined in point #1. Usually you can run scripts from the command line like this:

   ```
   mysql --user='cron_mysql_user'@'localhost' -pstrongpassword --execute="call proc_name()" db_name
   ```
6. You create nice reports based on your periodic snapshots :-)

The advantage of doing so is that you centralized I/O a few times a day only, a controlled manner, so you only have a very light SELECT statement to do when you need to know the statistics.

Comment: Thanks you so much :-) I'll give it a try, especially as it's a private dashboard so real-time data won't be insanely important. I'll let you know here if anything.